# How to remove null attributes from my JSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having a table which is storing the JSON values. Within these JSONs, the JSON is having null attributes like below :

```
{ 
  "name" : "AAAA",
  "department" : "BBBB",
  "countryCode" : null,
  "languageCode" : null,
  "region" : "AP"
}
```

I would like to write a query so that all the null attributes are removed from the output. For e.g. for the above-mentioned JSON, the resultant output JSON should be like this.

```
 {
   "name" : "AAAA",
   "department" : "BBBB",
   "region" : "AP"
 }
```

I would like to have a generic query which I can apply to any JSON to get rid of null attributes in MySQL (v5.7).

Comment: share your query

Comment: you can use JSON_REMOVE function of mysql.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will work for removing a single key value pair, where the value is `NULL`:

```
SELECT JSON_REMOVE(col, '$.countryCode')
FROM yourTable
WHERE CAST(col->"$.countryCode" AS CHAR(50)) = 'null';
```

But, I don't see a clean way of doing multiple removals in a single update.  We could try to chain the updates together, but that would be ugly and non readable.

Also, to check for your JSON null, I had to cast the value to text first.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't know all the keys in advance:

```sql
  WITH j AS (SELECT CAST('{"a": 1, "b": "null", "c": null}' AS JSON) o)
SELECT j.o, (SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(k, JSON_EXTRACT(j.o, CONCAT('$."', jt.k, '"')))
               FROM JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(o), '$[*]' COLUMNS (k VARCHAR(200) PATH '$')) jt
              WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(j.o, CONCAT('$."', jt.k, '"')) != CAST('null' AS JSON)) removed
  FROM j;
```

Outputs:

| o | removed |
| --- | --- |
| {"a": 1, "b": "null", "c": null} | {"a": 1, "b": "null"} |

And this will keep your keys with string value `"null"`, which is different from json `null`.

Comment: This needs a `COALESCE(JSON_OBJECTAGG(...), JSON_OBJECT())` for the edge case where `o` is an empty object

Answer (score 0):

How you can remove null keys using JSON_REMOVE function. $.dummy is used if the condition is false.

```
select json_remove(abc,
case when json_unquote(abc->'$.name') = 'null' then '$.name' else '$.dummy' end,
case when json_unquote(abc->'$.department') = 'null' then '$.department' else '$.dummy' end,
case when json_unquote(abc->'$.countryCode') = 'null' then '$.countryCode' else '$.dummy' end,
case when json_unquote(abc->'$.languageCode') = 'null' then '$.languageCode' else '$.dummy' end,
case when json_unquote(abc->'$.region') = 'null' then '$.region' else '$.dummy' end) 
from (
select cast('{ 
  "name" : "AAAA",
  "department" : "BBBB",
  "countryCode" : null,
  "languageCode" : null,
  "region" : "AP"
}' as json) as abc ) a
```

Output:

```
{"name": "AAAA", "region": "AP", "department": "BBBB"}
```